# Run Python script which needs /dev/mem permission without sudo

Tags: python, apache, flask, raspberry-pi, sudo

i wrote a python script which controls a LED strip over the gpio pins. Its working perfectly fine with sudo. I even got it working with the flask dev webserver, but when trying to deploy it with apache2 i cant manually put sudo in front of the command.

```
from rpi_ws281x import *

strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(110, 18, 800000, 10, False, 255, 0)
strip.begin()

strip.setPixelColor(1, Color(255,0,0))
strip.show()
```

This script lets the second Led of my led strip light up in red color.

The Raspberry has only this purpose, i would prefer to just give all access to the /dev/mem folder (I know that this is not recommended in security means).

I already tried updating the permissions with chown and chmod, i put myself in the /dev/gpiomem group and i set the user as root. But Sudo is still required, how can I solve it?

Running it without sudo results in this error due to missing permissions

```
Can't open /dev/mem: Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reset.py", line 4, in <module>
    strip.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rpi_ws281x/rpi_ws281x.py", line 131, in begin
    raise RuntimeError('ws2811_init failed with code {0} ({1})'.format(resp, str_resp))
RuntimeError: ws2811_init failed with code -5 (mmap() failed)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not configure `sudo` properly to allow password-less access to certain application?

Comment: I don’t exactly know what you mean by that, I added the root permissions to the user in the [forgot name ] file, but that didnt worl. Will try to find other options, thanks for your suggestion